# Asymetry in PC/SC Windows and PC/SC-lite for card Status

Tags: c++, cross-platform, driver, pcsc

while I reacently code PC/SC on Windows and Linux, I noticed a slight asymetry between the APIs of [pc/sc-lite](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/ifdhandler_8h.html) and the [IOCTL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/ff548988(v=vs.85).aspx) of winscard. Except for the fact, that you have to switch the ICTLs for yourself, Windows is able to pend a requests.

And here is where it gehts tricky:

- For pc/sc-lite there is [`IFDHICCPresence`](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/group__IFDHandler.html#gac0ef46f09df179c44a82259468bea174) to return the current card state.
- On winscard there are 3 of them

  - [`IOCTL_SMARTCARD_IS_ABSENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548905(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`IOCTL_SMARTCARD_PRESENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) have that wierd callback-semantic.
  - [`IOCTL_SMARTCARD_GET_STATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/hardware/ff548904(v=vs.85).aspx) on the other hand, is kind of the same as `IFDHICCPresence`. Beside the fact that Windows also supports swallowing and ejecting cards which pc/sc-lite don't.

I want to implement a platform independent IFD handler so a similar behavior would be much easier to handler. Of course I could add yet another layer to compensate for the windows specific part, but I want to save that as a last resort.

Isn't PC/SC and the IFD handlers supposed to be a standart with defined functions and behavior?

Is it possible to disable the callback behavior on Windows?

So far I tryed to define `IOCTL_SMARTCARD_IS_ABSENT/PRESENT` as unsupported, but Windows insists of calling them even though the information could retrieved with `IOCTL_SMARTCARD_GET_STATE`.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not possible to tell Windows that you don't support `IOCTL_SMARTCARD_IS_ABSENT` and `IOCTL_SMARTCARD_IS_PRESENT` as a driver. There is also a third way to get card state: IOCTL_SMARTCARD_GET_ATTRIBUTE ([SCardGetAttrib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379559(v=vs.85).aspx)) fetching `SCARD_ATTR_ICC_PRESENCE`.